# How to add WebPage in a panel

Tags: wicket-1.6, wicket-6

I need to add a Webpage on a panel, but as i am new to Wicket framewrok.I have no idea.
Can anybody please give me an example?

```
public Component renderBody(String componentId) {
    //return new Label(componentId, getMessage()).add(new AttributeAppender("class", "p8p"));
    return new TablePanel(componentId);
    //return new MainSearchTab();

}
```

I have  a panel named TablePanel instead of that i want to use a WebPage, here MainSearchTab.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `InlineFrame`:

Java:

```
InlineFrame frame = new InlineFrame("webpage", OtherPage.class);
frame.setMarkupId("webpage");
add(frame.setOutputMarkupId(true));
```

HTML:

```
<iframe wicket:id="webpage" name="webpage"></iframe>
```